# Binary compatibility of .Net interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, interface, backwards-compatibility, missingmethodexception

Say we have a base interface defined in C# like so:

```
interface IBase
{
    int Prop1 { get; set }
    string Prop2 { get; set }
}
```

Then we have a derived interface as follows:

```
interface ISub1: IBase
{
    int Prop3 { get; set }
}
```

These interfaces are defined in an API assembly against which custom applications compile and run. (The assembly also includes non-exposed classes which implement these interfaces and public factory methods for obtaining instances). All extant code uses `ISub1`, there is no existing code which directly references `IBase`. It was done this way in anticipation that we might eventually want to introduce a second derived interface `ISub2`, as a peer of `ISub1`, and that has now come to pass. Unfortunately though we find that `ISub2` should not contain `Prop2` (only Prop1 and some additional unique properties), hence we want to "demote" that property down into `ISub1`, resulting in the following revised interfaces:

```
interface IBase
{
    int Prop1 { get; set }
}

interface ISub1: IBase
{
    string Prop2 { get; set }
    int Prop3 { get; set }
}

interface ISub2: IBase
{
    string Prop4 { get; set }
}
```

Given that there are no consumers of `IBase` it seems like we should be able to do this with impunity (and I'm fairly sure we could do that in Java), but when attempting to do so we have run into a binary compatibility problem with code compiled against the old interface definitions. Specifically:

```
ISub1 s1 = ... // get an instance
s1.Prop2 = "help";
```

This code, when run against the new interface definition, fails with an exception as follows:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void
>   MyNamespace.IBase.set_Prop2(System.String)'.

Note the reference to `IBase`. I presume this to be because the seeming call to `ISub1.set_Prop2` has been compiled with a tight binding to where `Prop2` is actually introduced, in `IBase`.

Can anyone help me with a way out of this conundrum? I.e. is there a way to re-factor the interfaces so that the definition of ISub2 is "clean" (does not include the extraneous Prop2)? Asking all existing applications to recompile is out of the question.

Comment: You're rather stuck.

Comment: I code OOP in C# for more than 8 years and i do not understand your problem. You should just check if interfaces were not changed, and you have builds with equal .Net/interface versions. And.. there is no binary vtable in C#/net

Comment: If IBase defines Prop2, and ISub2 implements IBase, then ISub2 must also implement Prop2. It seems to be a pretty straightforward issue.

Comment: Could you summarize the structure before and after? It seems a little unclear from your writeup where Prop2 is defined and was defined.

Comment: Made some edits to make it (hopefully) clearer what the aim is.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of hacky and not sure it will work but maybe worth a try

```
interface IBase0
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
interface IBase : IBase0
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
interface ISub1: IBase
{
    int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
interface ISub2 : IBase0
{
    int Prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I should have mentioned that I tried that and it is a possible though inelegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

By writing it in [TryRoslyn](http://goo.gl/dmuV2i) it becomes quite evident that there is a difference based on where you put the property in the interface:

Given:

```
interface ISub1A: IBaseA
{
    int Prop3 { get; set; }
}

interface IBaseA
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

interface ISub1B: IBaseB
{
    int Prop3 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

interface IBaseB
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
ISub1A a = null;
a.Prop2 = "Hello";

ISub1B b = null;
b.Prop2 = "Hello";
```

(note that in both cases I'm using the `ISub1*` interface in C# code)

The generated IL code is:

```
IL_0001: ldstr "Hello"
IL_0006: callvirt instance void IBaseA::set_Prop2(string)
IL_000b: ldnull
IL_000c: ldstr "Hello"
IL_0011: callvirt instance void ISub1B::set_Prop2(string)
```

so the IL code "correctly" resolves to the interface where the property is really defined.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this:

```
interface ISub1: IBase
```

Just says "any class that implements `ISub1` will promise to also implement `IBase`". There's no mixing of the methods defined within each interface, such that it also means "`ISub1` contains 3 properties, `Prop1` - `Prop3`".

So that's why it's not working. `ISub1` is currently defined to require exactly one property called `Prop3`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should hide `ISub2.Prop2` by [implementing it explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). Then, depending on why `ISub2` should not contain `Prop2`, you should either deprecate that implementation using the [ObsoleteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute or throw an [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) from both accessors.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is quite old, I want to mention a similar problem I had, when splitting up an interface into a base and inheriting type. Because it was part of a Nuget package with the same major release version, it had to be downward compatible with previous versions. I solved it by duplicating the members in the original interface with the "new" keyword.

[MissingMethodException after extracting base interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061714/missingmethodexception-after-extracting-base-interface)